# Rewards for the best answer from the 1st quarter of 2017

Tags: discussion, answers, scheduled-event

Inspired by the mods of a few other communities, this is a continuation of a series of quarterly rewards for the best answer, and I'd ask the community for the best answers from the past quarter to get an additional reward:

**Please link to an answer which was created from January 1st 2017 through March 31st 2017 and which you think deserves an additional reward. Only one entry per answer will be valid. For multiple favorites submit separate answers to this post.**

Here is a data query to help with the decision making process:

- **[Answers with most votes from 1st quarter of 2017](http://data.stackexchange.com/salesforce/query/edit/652089)**

If your answer isn't linked on the list above, no problem! You are free to choose your own favorite answer which didn't get the limelight. Any nominated answer can be from you or from someone else.

The highest voted answer of this meta post will be picked up for the reward of 200 points after 2 weeks.

Note: Answer must have 1+ upvote and submitted in the same quarter only. Answer should not be a wiki. Please only propose one post in any answer here so the votes can easily be tallied.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would like to nominate [Santanu Halder](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/18875/santanu-halder)'s [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/159036/29317) to the question:-

**[Refresh lightning component Opportunity page on Stage progress bar](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/158222/29317)**

Reasons:-

- Unique question with very **interesting use case** (which I thought wouldn't be possible)
- And a great(*as in, again interesting*) workaround for the same

Comment: Can you add just a brief explanation of *why* you think it is a good answer?

Comment: Done. (y) @AdrianLarson

Answer (score 10):

I love this question and SFDCFox's answer to it. This is a behavior of Salesforce that is not innately intuitive and can lead to many hours of frustrated troubleshooting.

I am happy that this information is out there: [Unable to rerender in visualforce Component](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/165153/unable-to-rerender-in-visualforce-component/166274#166274)

Comment: My pick as well for the exact same reasons.

Answer (score 10):

I'm nominating the fox too, for this one:

[Can Queueable Apex Jobs Run in Parallel?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/165430/can-queueable-apex-jobs-run-in-parallel)

Not because it was my question, but because he got an answer to an oddball question in the time it took for me to fly from Melbourne to Sydney :)

Answer (score 9):

I want to nominate [Rahul Sharma](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/4726)'s answer to this question:

[Unknown Error Parsing Lead Query](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/163002/2995)

It's an age old solution to a common problem. Can't compare field to field in a query? Use a formula!

Comment: Classic but still relevant !

Answer (score 4):

I will be nominating sfdcfox for my question

[SOQL results returning RecordTypeId which is not included in query](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/155979/soql-results-returning-recordtypeid-which-is-not-included-in-query)

Answer (score 2):

I am nominating @Derek F answer for the following post

[Need help regarding Validation rule](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/166921/need-help-regarding-validation-rule/166931#166931)

The way the answer has been constructed deserves applauds. Derek answered the correct and scalabale way to implement than providing a workable solution to the problem.

Comment: I think [this](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/166931/29317) is the answer which you're referring to. Current link points to your answer for me. :) (Please remove `166923#166923` in the end of the above link, so it points to the question itself)

Comment: @SE_User done, thanks :)